# Determining relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

I am reading a mathematics book and I am quite confused at this highlighted sentence (it's not about the mathematical context but about the grammar):

[image]

Is a verb missing in the relative clause "that a random variable X [...]"?

In my opinion, I would understand this sentence as:

> When the target space T is continuous, e.g., the real line R, it is more natural to specify the probability (that a random variable X takes) is in an interval, denoted by [...].

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand the sentence now. Regarding the screenshot, since it contains some mathematical expressions and I cannot write them so I use the screenshot. I will be careful next time.

Comment: The mathematical symbols are not relevant to the grammar. However, they can be pasted: P ( a ⩽ X ⩽ B ) for a < b - You can find mathematical symbols in text form on some web site by a Google search and then copy and paste.   Or use the Character Map app in Windows ≤≤≤≤≤ or type in Microsoft Word using Insert Symbol then copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I parsed it as follows

> [a random variable is in an interval]
> [the probability that [a random variable is in an interval]]
> [it's more natural to specify [the probability that [a random variable is in an interval]]]

*is* is the verb in the first clause.